# Finding the corresponding item in two tuples with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples containing data, and another corresponding tuple containing some header information.  Based on the header, I would like to extract a specific value from a given element in the list.  Example:

```
>>> hdr = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
>>> elt = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> my_func(elt, "c")
3
```

The key here is that I know the header names ahead of time but not their position in the header tuple.  What is the easiest way to find the value in `elt` corresponding to `"c"` in `hdr`?  I am using Python 3.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easiest?

```
dict(zip(hdr, elt))["c"]
```

An alternative would be:

```
elt[hdr.index("c")]
```

However building a `dict` (as per the first suggestion) would be more efficient if you're making repeated searches.

Comment: +1 on that, avoid the index solution if you need efficiency. You probably need if it is more than one call.

Answer (score 1):

what about the `.index` method?

```
hdr.index("c") + 1
```